# Socket.Receive is dropping the last byte of every packet

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I am having trouble with a socket client application written in vb.net using Visual Studio 2005.  The client connects to a C language socket server that is running on OpenVMS.  The problem that I have is that when the server sends a packet, the client does not receive the last byte (of every packet!).  I can dump the packets on the network and the data is all there.  My current solution is to keep my socket messages short (247 bytes) and send one extra byte past the end of my data.

I would like to include more information in my messages and I cannot find a way to make this work.  If I knew 100% how long the packets will be on the network, I could work around this by including an extra byte in just the right places.  However, I don't want to make any assumptions about the length of the packets.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what the best solution is to this problem?

Here is a sample of my client receive code:

```
Private Sub ReceiveMsg()
    Dim nTotalBytes As Integer
    Dim nNumBytes As Integer
    Dim nMsgType As Short
    Dim nMsgLen As Short
    Dim ind As Integer

    Try
        nNumBytes = -1
        While (nNumBytes <> 0)

            nTotalBytes = 0
            RecvBuffer.Initialize()

            nNumBytes = ClientSocket.Receive(RecvBuffer, nTotalBytes, 4, SocketFlags.None)
            If nNumBytes > 3 Then
                SyncLock ClientSocket
                    AppendText("")
                    AppendText("Message Received " & Str(nNumBytes) & " Bytes")
                    nTotalBytes = nTotalBytes + nNumBytes
                    nMsgType = BitConverter.ToInt16(RecvBuffer, 0)
                    nMsgLen = BitConverter.ToInt16(RecvBuffer, 2)
                    If nMsgLen > 8191 Then
                        AppendText(" Error - Message length invalid: " & Str(nMsgLen))
                        nMsgLen = 250
                    End If

                    While (nTotalBytes < nMsgLen And nNumBytes > 0)
                        nNumBytes = ClientSocket.Receive(RecvBuffer, nTotalBytes, (nMsgLen - nTotalBytes), _
                                                        SocketFlags.None)
                        AppendText("Message Received " & Str(nNumBytes) & " Bytes")
                        nTotalBytes = nTotalBytes + nNumBytes
                    End While
                End SyncLock

                AppendText("Total Bytes Received = " & Str(nTotalBytes))
                AppendText("MsgLen from Message = " & Str(nMsgLen))
                Select Case nMsgType
                    Case 1
                        AppendText(" Liftpos = " & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RecvBuffer, 4, 1))

                        For ind = 0 To NUM_LOCATIONS - 1
                            Number(ind) = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RecvBuffer, 5 + (ind * 12), 12)
                        Next

                        RefreshScreen()

                    Case Else
                        AppendText(" Unrecognized message type: " & Str(nMsgType))

                End Select

            End If
        End While


    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Tell the main thread to invoke DisconnectedUI
        Dim cb As New SimpleCallback(AddressOf DisconnectedUI)
        Me.Invoke(cb)
        Return
    End Try
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  What is quite mysterious is how *you* can fix this problem by sending an extra byte.  You said that the *server* message is missing a byte.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been corrected.  The TCP/IP server was using a WRITE function modifier that ended up setting the URG bit in the TCP/IP packets.  I believe that the server mangled this and different Windows clients had a variety of problems handling these packets.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, sending an extra byte does NOT fix the problem.  As long as I keep my socket message under about 247 bytes, it all gets send in a single packet.  Therefore sending an extra byte just makes sure that all of the data is received by the client.

If I send a longer message, then depending on the lenght of the message, one byte is lost at the end of each packet.  This means that if I send a longer message, I would have to adjust for this by either making the assumption that it will always be the same or by including a tag of some kind to help me find the offset of the data in the message.

I thought that there should be some better solution.